# Prove that if $a\nmid b$, $ax^3+bx+(b+a)=0$ has no natural number solutions

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility, cubics

Let $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ with $a\neq0$. I need to prove that if $a\nmid b$, then the equation $ax^3+bx+(b+a)=0$ does not have a solution that is a natural number.

I noticed that regardless of the values of $a$ and $b$, the equation will always have a root at $-1$ (i.e. $ax^3+bx+(b+a)=a(x^2-x+(1+\frac{b}{a}))(x+1)$.

So now the problem reduces to proving that if $a\nmid b$, $x^2-x+(1+\frac{b}{a})=0$ has no natural number solutions. I've used the quadratic formula and tried to analyse this a number of ways but I'm quite stuck.

Comment: If $x$ is root of the quadratic then $\,{-}\color{#c00}{b = a}(x^2-x+1)\ \ $ so $\,x\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{a\mid b}\ \ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque As I suggested in my comment in my deleted answer, you should consider posting an answer based on your comment.

Comment: @John Why don't you simply repost your deleted answer as a new CW answer? It will save time for all.

Comment: @BillDubuque I thought it would be more fair, and appropriate, that you post an answer. However, I've instead done what you suggested, i.e., reposted my previous answer as a new CW one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quadratic equation is, with the factor of $a$ included,

$$ax^2 - ax + a + b = 0 \implies b = -a(x^2 - x + 1) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523960/prove-that-if-a-nmid-b-ax3bxba-0-has-no-natural-number-solutions/3523967#comment7247591_3523960) states, for $x \in \mathbb{N}$, you have $a$ dividing the right hand side, so it must also divide the left hand side, i.e., $b$. Thus, you require $a \mid b$. However, since you're given $a \not\mid b$, this can't be true, meaning there is no natural number solution for $x$.